# エラーが起きてしまい、偶数と奇数の判別ができない。

Tags: python

画像のようにしたところｎの部分にエラーが起きてしまいました。
下の形態はなるべく崩さず、ｎの部分だけ直して動かすことは可能でしょうか。

[image]

Comment: コードは画像ではなくテキスト（マークダウン）で記入しましょう。

Comment: 既に回答が付いた状態なので、大幅に意味を変えるような編集は控えてください。別の疑問がある場合には新しい質問として投稿し直してください。

Answer (score 4):

`else` の部分には条件文を書かず、単に `else` のみを記述します。

`if` 文の判定 "以外" が `else` のところで実行されますが、今回の場合なら偶数か奇数どちらか一方を判定できれば残りは自明なはずです。

Answer (score 2):

問題の行は

```
  elif n % 2 == 1:
```

ではないでしょうか？